# What's the maximum time to leave once student status expires

Tags: usa, immigration, student-visa

If a non-citizen of the US has been able to live in the country for some time under a student visa, and their educational program ends, how long do they have to leave the country (e.g. before forced deportation hearings get started)? The USCIS must have a basic fixed policy.

Also, if the case is different but the only difference is a work visa instead, how long after work visa is no longer good must person leave?

Comment: This is really too legal to be a fit.  I would suggest you ask on expatriates.se

Answer (score 4):

There are options available for when your program ends you can look at [SEVIS #10](http://www.ice.gov/sevis/students/) to see what they are.

There is also discussion on the subject at the [SEVIS F1 transfers](http://www.ice.gov/sevis/f_1_transfers.htm#_Toc174419530) page:

> If USCIS denies the reinstatement application , the student must leave the United States immediately or risk being placed in removal proceedings at any time under §237(a)(C)(i) of the Immigration and Nationality Act (INA), as amended.

There are always other options that you can exploit with respect to changing your status but you can if not you have [60 day grace period](http://www.ice.gov/sevis/employment/faq_f_on1.htm#_1_14) from the time of the program's end to the time you have to leave the country:

> **1.14. May an F-1 student work on campus during the 60-day grace period after the program end date?**
>
> No. The 60-day "grace" period after graduation or post-completion OPT is for an F-1 student to prepare to leave the United States, unless the student is beginning a new program of study. An F-1 student may consider applying for post-completion OPT to continue working after graduation.