# How does US J1 visa termination affect a UK Tier 4 student visa application?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, j-visa, student-visa

In 2012 I participated in "Work and Travel" student exchange program and obtained J1 visa. But because of conflict with my employer the program was terminated and I had to come back. The problem is that visa sponsor gave me only 5 days to leave USA. Since there were no affordable tickets available on that dates, I overstayed for a week. Is this considered as violation?

Now I am completing my Tier 4 (General) visa application. How do I answer to this question: "Have you been deported, removed or otherwise required to leave any country including the UK in the last 10 years?"

I didn't get any official order of removal only notified by sponsor employee by phone.

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2608/whats-the-maximum-time-to-leave-once-student-status-expires/

Answer (score 1):

The reason you had to leave the USA is related to your employer there, not breaking USA immigration law.

Therefore, if I was faced with that question, I would answer **No**.

Comment: Opinion is an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

From your description your visa expired therefore you left before any authority formally requested or forcibly removed you form the country. You simply followed the immigration law in place.  Therefore the answer would be no in my personal opinion. In doubt you can always either contact your embassy in London or the British embassy in your country.